# notification for audio session interruption

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, avaudiosession

In my app, I am running a background service, I want my service be notified if another app is playing audio e.g. phone call or a music app or Radio app is playing audio.

From the AVAudioSession class documentation, seems this [AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification) is the thing I need.

So, I tried:

```
-(void)initialization{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:)
                                                         name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                                       object:nil];
}

-(void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification{
   NSLog("Get notified for interruption");
}
```

I run my app on iphone. When I make outgoing/incoming phone call, my app get notified for audio session interruption. It works well!

But when I open a radio/music app playing audio, my app is not notified. Why? How can my app get notified when music/radio app is playing audio?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs::

/* Registered listeners will be notified when the system has interrupted the audio session and when
 the interruption has ended.  Check the notification's userInfo dictionary for the interruption type -- either begin or end.
 In the case of an end interruption notification, check the userInfo dictionary for AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions that
 indicate whether audio playback should resume.
 */

SO basically if any other app is trying to take over the audio session, then the interruption notification will be posted.

For example: try opening the apple's default music app or try recording a video from the default camera application. They take over the audio session and you will be notified of the same.

Just to be on the safe side:: 
the instance listening to the notification should still be alive in the memory.